# Strange Exchange send-connector behaviour

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-server

Can anyone explain this?

- Two Exchange servers, EX1 (2010, yes, I know) and EX2 (2016). Both are in the same IP subnet.
- A send connector on EX2 with a scope for 'domain.com' routing through a smarthost, and a send connector on EX1 with a scope for '*' routing through MX record.

When I set the send connector on EX2 to non-scoped, a mail sent to 'user@domain.com' ends up in Submission with 'mailloop detected'. When I set the send connector on EX2 to scoped, the mail is sent successfully through the smarthost.

As far as I understand scoping for a send connector, this shouldn't make any difference for this scenario because both servers are in the same AD site, but why does it work with scoped connector turned on and not when it's off?

Joost

Comment: Any updates on your issue?

Comment: I've disabled the send connector on the 2010 server and changed the domain of the send connector on the 2016 server to *, and now everything works as expected, even when disabling scoping.

But I still don't have an explanation why a mailloop occurred when the send connector was not scoped, and the mail was sent successfully when it was scoped.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command to check if there is any other send connector in your environment:

```
 Get-sendconnector | FL
```

Then run [message tracking log](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-logs/message-tracking?view=exchserver-2019) to check the detailed information of the mail delivery.

Comment: The two connectors I mentioned (* on EX1 using MX and domain.com on EX2 using smarthost) were the only two send connectors.
I've deleted the EX1 send connector and changed the domain on the EX2 send connector from domain.com to * and now everything is sent through the smarthost, so the problem is solved. I still don't have an explanation why changing the 'scoped send connector' setting would result in a mailloop however.